# Converting custom_rules.xml to a gradle version

Tags: android, ant, gradle

I'm working on an existing project that relies heavily on a lot of configuration from a custom_rules.xml ant build. I've looked around online but have yet to come across anything explicitly dealing with such a task in great detail. I've played around with Gradle and tried doing some suggested approaches but nothing has worked yet. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: This is what I need to rebuild using Gradle. I would love to get rid off doing this via command line not to mention handling dependencies and etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

SET PRE COMPILE

```
<!-- ========================================================================================= -->
<!-- Once update android SDK, please copy this target from build.xml under android SDK         -->
<!-- ========================================================================================= -->

<!-- Updates the pre-processed PNG cache -->
<target name="-crunch">
    <echo>SET CRUNCH</echo>
    <exec executable="${aapt}" taskName="crunch">
        <arg value="crunch" />
        <arg value="-v" />
        <arg value="-S" />
        <arg path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        <arg value="-C" />
        <arg path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
    </exec>
</target>

<!-- ========================================================================================= -->
<!-- Once update android SDK, please copy this target from build.xml under android SDK         -->
<!-- ========================================================================================= -->

<!-- Puts the project's resources into the output package file
     This actually can create multiple resource package in case
     Some custom apk with specific configuration have been
     declared in default.properties.
     -->
<target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
    <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
    <echo>MADE IT TO CRUNCH</echo>
    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
        <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package"
                versioncode="${version.code}"
                versionname="${version.name}"
                debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                buildType="${build.target}"
                ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
                manifestpackage="com.myproj">
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
            <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
            <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
        </aapt>
    </do-only-if-not-library>
</target>

<target name="-post-package" >
    <property name="config_path" location="${cert.dir}" />
    <property name="out.pre.signlib.signed.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}-release-pre-signlib-sign.apk" />
    <property name="out.signlib.signed.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}-release-signlib-signed.apk" />
    <echo>sign with signlib certificate</echo>
    <touch file="res/raw/my.properties"/>
    <copy file="${out.packaged.file}" tofile="${out.pre.signlib.signed.file}"/>
    <java jar="apksigtool.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">      
        <arg value="${out.packaged.file}"/>
        <arg value="private_key.der" />
        <arg value="my.crt" />
    </java>
    <copy file="${out.packaged.file}" tofile="${out.signlib.signed.file}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to do and what type of data is in your custom_rules.xml?  Gradle is more than just build rules, you can use it to write functions or even classes so it is capable of doing whatever you need with some customization.

Comment: The custom_rules file in my project imports other stand alone projects and creates files in the src root of that project structure in eclipse. It also includes some certificates and creates multiple apk files in different configurations. The other projects were built seperate for testing purposes. Im trying to re-configure the entire project to use gradle rather than leave it the way it is so I no longer have to build from the command line.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the question is, but you'll have to port the build to Gradle.

Comment: Ive added my custom_rules.xml if that helps with an idea of what Im trying to convert and do in gradle

Comment: Ok, signing should be easy by signing configs. Checking your special resource processing

Comment: @EugenMartynov is that something in the studio UI?

Comment: It looks like crunch is on by default in the gradle build. So nothing should stop you to convert ant build to gradle